# how to chmod a file in windows 8.1 to 666 so that i can run a script on xampp

Tags: xampp

A premium script for file hosting sites:

- `CHMOD` the folder "data" to 777
- `CHMOD` file "data/account.dat" to 666
- `CHMOD` file "data/config.dat" to 666
- `CHMOD` file "data/cookie.dat" to 666
- `CHMOD` file "data/online.dat" to 666
- `CHMOD` file "data/log.txt" to 666

How to perform it on windows 8.1 in xampp?

Comment: `chmod` doesn't exist on Windows, there are file permissions though, why do you need it to be `666` ?

Comment: 666 => is global `rw` and 777 => `x` also includes an execute, those are VERY insecure settings, who recommended this?

Comment: @nrathaus - I assume data is a folder that should be written to by the webserver, which is rarely running as the same user as the file owner. Since data is a folder, it requires the execute bit so that the user can enter it.

Comment: 666 and 777 are allow `other` to write, this isn't secure in any way possible or imaginable